# PHP header redriction to new page

Tags: php

I would like to click on a hyperlink which will go to page 2, but I also want to open a new blank page.

I tried:

```
header "Location: http://bing.com";
header ("Location: http://bing.com", false);
header ("Location: http://bing.com", true, 301);
```

I'd like to use only php to open the new blank page.

Comment: ```php   
header('Location: http://bing.com', true, 303);
```
Gives me a new tab/page - Firefox / Brave (10/2022)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this from the header redirection. You need `target="_blank"` attribute added to your `<A>` in HTML. Or do the trick where your redirection redirects to the page that would use JavaScript to do that for you (expect it to be blocked by the browsers anti-popup feature though)

Comment: i will add target="_blank" to a tag

Answer (score 2):

You cannot open a new window from doing a header redirection. You must use Javascript.

If you need to do it with PHP for some reason, you could print the Javascript like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script>window.open("http://www.google.com/");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: i need to record a click thats why i was looking for php as makes it easier to do this rather then me writing a ajax function

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to do this. PHP cannot control the window. You will have to use Javascript in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with PHP. If you want to open 2 pages at once (replace the current, and open a second tab/window) you must do this with javascript.

Comment: So only way I can do this is with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One of the perfect solution to it which I found here only and you can do one thing is that which page you want to open along with other one put the code below in a PHP page the one needs to be opened and this code will pop up for the link provided in place of default link.

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">  window.open('http://reliable4you.com/', '_blank')  </script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for new tab and its working perfectly.
Just only care about your file location.

CODE:

```js
<?php 
          if(isset($_POST['button']))
             {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                 echo 'window.open( "/Projectfolder/File.php" )';
                 echo '</script>';
              }
          ?>
```